# The last step of the Longstaff-Schwartz method

Tags: monte-carlo, american-options

I'm reading [An analysis of the Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm for American option pricing](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/9176/TR001296.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), by Clement, Lamberton and Protter.

They define the stopping times (top of page 4)

$$ \tau_j^{[m]} =
\begin{cases}
 L & \text{ if } j = L\\
 j \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ Z_j \ge P_j^m(Z_{\tau_{j+1}^{[m]}})\right\}} + \tau_{j+1}^{[m]} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ Z_j < P_j^m(Z_{\tau_{j+1}^{[m]}})\right\}} & \text{ if } j \le L-1
\end{cases}
$$

And then obtain the approximate value function (equation 2.1)
$$ U_0^{[m]} = \max \left( Z_0, \mathbb{E} Z_{\tau_1^{[m]}} \right)$$

My question is, why didn't they take the more natural 
$$ U_0^{[m]} = \mathbb{E} Z_{\tau_0^{[m]}}$$
instead?

When implementing Longstaff-Schwartz (see equation 2.2 and above), this choice actually makes a difference, as they introduce some high-bias (Jensen)
$$ U_0^{m, N}  = \max \left(Z_0, \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N Z^{(n)}_{\tau_1^{n, m, N}}\right) $$
instead of
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N Z^{(n)}_{\tau_0^{n, m, N}}
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N  \max \left(Z_0, Z^{(n)}_{\tau_1^{n, m, N}}\right) $$